# Adding a truth-like predicate to PA

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory

It is well known that adding a truth predicate to arithmetic in the most natural way leads to a contradiction.

Suppose as usual that we add a one place relation *T* to the language of arithmetic, and define some system of Godel numbering $\ulcorner \cdot \urcorner$ for this expanded language. Given a set of axioms A in this language (e.g., PA), we extend the usual provability relation $A \vdash \phi$ by demanding that it satisfy the following:

R1. if $A \vdash \phi$, then $A \vdash T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$

R2. if $A \vdash T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$, then $A \vdash \phi$

R3. if $A \vdash \neg \phi$, then $A \vdash \neg T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$

R4. if $A \vdash \neg T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$, then $A \vdash \neg \phi$

Notes:

• We are not adding any new axioms (in particular, we are not adding any Tarski biconditionals $\phi \leftrightarrow T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$ to A), or any other rules of inference of any sort related to $T$. All we are adding to A are the above rules.

• Requirements R1-R4 are different from adding rules of inference. Obviously, adding rules of inference that tell that us we can go from $\phi$ to $T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$ and back, and $\neg \phi$ to $\neg T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$ and back, would be too strong and lead to contradictions in well known ways if A is sufficiently strong. Loosely speaking, with R1-R4, we can't reason *hypothetically* about truth, though we can talk about the truth or falsity of something when we've actually established its truth or falsity.

Question: Given the above requirements, do we nevertheless have $PA \vdash \bot$ ?

Comment: Could you clarify a little what you mean? Your requirements all have empty left-hand side (that is, there is no theory preceding $\vdash$), but then later you refer to $PA\vdash\perp$. Do you intend that R1 etc. hold also with respect to any theory, or are you only requiring them for the empty theory, or what?

Comment: I intend that these rules apply to whatever theory we are working with (in my case, PA). I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Obviously, adding rules of inference that tell that us we can go from $\phi$ to $T(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$ and back, and $\neg\phi$ to $\neg T(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$ and back, would be too strong and lead to contradictions in well known ways.

Actually, that's not correct. According to [a theorem of Friedman and Sheard](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016800728790073X) these rules (denoted by them "$T$-intro", "$T$-elim", "$\neg T$-intro", and "$\neg T$-elim") can be consistently added to PA. (See part D of their main theorem.) [Edit: to clarify, this is in the context of Hilbert-style deduction. If these rules of inference were included in a natural deduction system then they could be converted to implications using $\to$-introduction, and then you would get the Tarski biconditionals and a liar paradox.]

I may add that I have formulated an extension $S$ of Peano arithmetic which is consistent, includes the capture scheme $\phi \to T(\ulcorner \phi\urcorner)$ for every sentence $\phi$, and for which $T(\ulcorner T(\ulcorner \cdots \ulcorner\phi\urcorner \cdots \urcorner)\urcorner)$ is not a theorem, for any false arithmetical sentence $\phi$. Thus if the release scheme "infer $\phi$ from $T(\ulcorner \phi\urcorner)$" were added it would still be consistent. Incidentally, this system has the remarkable property that it proves its own soundness and consistency in the sense that it proves the sentences $$(\forall n)({\rm Prov}_S(n) \to T(n))$$ and $$T(\ulcorner{\rm Con}(S)\urcorner).$$ See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.3626.pdf) or [my book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814619957). (Note that my system uses intuitionistic logic, although it includes the law of excluded middle for every sentence of arithmetic.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at all those materials, they sound fascinating. Still, I'm puzzled about the Friedman and Sheard result - if the rest of the logic is standard, and T-intro etc. mean what one would think, wouldn't one then able to prove every Tarksi biconditional, and thus get into trouble by considering Liar type sentences defined by the usual diagonalization method?

Comment: Well, if you can prove $\phi$ then you can infer $T(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$, and then $\phi \leftrightarrow T(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$ follows trivially, but there's no technique for proving biconditionals generally. You explained why yourself: we can't reason hypothetically about truth, we can only talk about the truth or falsity of something when we've actually established its truth or falsity.

Comment: ... $T$-intro etc. are deduction rules, not axiom schemes.

Comment: Yes, looking at their paper, T-intro etc. do seem to be just the rules R1-R4, rather than the more general sort of deduction rule that applies even in hypothetical reasoning.

Comment: @CeciliaBurrow To get a Liar paradox, you need to make T and the system where you add these axioms in such way that they are the same.

Comment: Just to clear up some confusions here and make it easy for the reader: we need to distinguish rules of inference that apply *anywhere* (even within hypothetical reasoning) from rules of inference of the form R1-R4, which only take complete proofs to complete proofs. I don't know that there is accepted terminology here, but let's call call the former a 'rule of inference' and the later a 'proof transformation rule.'

Comment: (cont'd) If T-intro, etc., are taken to be rules of inference, then a contradiction does indeed follow, but if they are only taken to be proof transformation rules, then the Friedman Sheard paper shows that we do not get a contradiction. In that sense, the Friedman Sheard result answers my question.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what was bothering you. Yes, these are rules of inference for Hilbert-style reasoning. Of course if you allowed them in natural deduction then you could use $\to$-introduction to turn them into implications.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to clarify that.